# How the pokemon's gender is determined for a mystery gift code?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

I had a mystery gift code for a shiny Gengar in Pokemon X/Y that I used today.

I want a male Gengar, but after ~ 50 resets, I only had females ones. The nature and stats change every time, but the gender looks preset somehow.

Do you know which factors determine the gender for a mystery gift code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gender is set when you receive the wonder card, whereas the nature and IVs are set when you receive the Pokemon from the npc.
**You can't soft-reset for gender**, but you can for nature and IVs.

P.S sometimes the gender is pre-set, so there's no way to get a different gender at all.